# Disable select query for database generated values in entity framework core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I was wondering if it's possible to disable the select query for database generated values in entity framework core without modifying the entity configuration for a specific DbContext?

I have to use an existing DbContext (a DbContext what I can't modify and is also used by other applications). In this DbContext there's a entity configuration for each entity. This DbContext will be used for inserting many records over a x period of time in batches. Because all those entities having a key property (and other properties what are marked as `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` or `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate`), after each insert, an select query is automatically done (for retrieving the key from the database and other values that are marked as `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` or `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate`). Is there any configuration what can be done to prevent this behaviour (stopping the `select` query) without modifying the entity configuration?